# How do I align element centered vertically?

Tags: css, center, css-tables

I'm sure this question has been asked many times. I believe I know the correct method, but it's not working for me.

I have a parent element that is a table, then a child element that is a table-cell marked to align vertically centered. Then within the child element, I have a span - the span should center vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmFcd/6/

```
<style type="text/css">
.breadcrumb{display:none;}
.bulletwrapper{width:840px; margin:0 auto; clear:both; overflow:auto; display:table;}
#bullet1{float:left; background:url(http://www.raceramps.com/images/trailerhaulload/BULLET1-heavy-boards.jpg) left no-repeat;}
#bullet2{float:right;background:url(http://www.raceramps.com/images/trailerhaulload/BULLET2-lightweight.jpg) left no-repeat;}
.bulletwrapper2{width:410px;  left no-repeat; height:94px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.bulletwrapper2 span{width:285px; float:right; border:#999 thin solid; border-radius:5px; padding:10px;}
</style>

<div class="bulletwrapper">
<div id="bullet1" class="bulletwrapper2"><span>No more heavy boards that can break, shoot like projectiles, or break your back hauling around!</span></div>
<div id="bullet2" class="bulletwrapper2"><span>Lightweight - the largest ramp weighs less than 20lbs!</span></div>

</div>​
```

I see the same concept on http://jaredjohnson.me, but it doesn't work for me for some reason?

Comment: you should format your css and put it in the css pane on that fiddle, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: you have all divs and no tables in your example

Comment: they are divs formatted as tables...

Comment: Obviously I don't know everything you're doing here, but it looks like you should be using `ul` and `li` instead of `div`s to be semantically correct and ensure the content is handled well on all browsers/platforms. Won't help you with vertically aligning the content, but then again, you couldn't be bothered to Google it first (there are a million tutorials out there).

Comment: I don't say this to be antagonistic, but I wouldn't have gotten this far trying the method I am without google. Be constructive in your criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` from your `#bullet2` & `#bullet1` DIV.

Answer (score 0):

this made the 2 divs stack in the middle

```
.breadcrumb{display:none;}
.bulletwrapper{width:840px; margin:0 auto; clear:both; overflow:auto; display:table;}
#bullet1{  background:url(http://www.raceramps.com/images/trailerhaulload/BULLET1-heavy-  boards.jpg) left no-repeat;}
#bullet2{background:url(http://www.raceramps.com/images/trailerhaulload/BULLET2-lightweight.jpg) left no-repeat;}
.bulletwrapper2{width:410px; height:94px; margin:0 auto; clear:both;  }
.bulletwrapper2 span{width:285px; float:right; border:#999 thin solid; border-radius:5px; padding:10px;clear:both;}
```